# How to use `\mathrm` in Beamer with `luatexja-preset`?

Tags: beamer, luatexja

```
lualatex t.tex
```

for the following code

```
% t.tex
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{luatexja-preset}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
$\mathrm{a}$
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

results in the following error

```
! LaTeX Error: Math alphabet identifier \mathrm is undefined in math version `n
ormal'.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.10 \end{frame}
```

`t.tex` compiles without the error if I comment out the line

```
\usepackage{luatexja-preset}
```

Comment: the package redefines mathnormal not to have any alphabets other than `\mathgt`if `\mathgt` doesn't select the required font then which font do you want `\mathrm` to select. (Sorry I find the documentation for luatexja a bit hard to follow:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks for your analysis. Opened an issue in LuaTeX-ja ticket system. https://osdn.net/ticket/browse.php?group_id=5593&tid=36711

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

```
% t.tex
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[professionalfonts]{beamer}

\usepackage{luatexja-preset}

\DeclareMathAlphabet\mathrM{\encodingdefault}{\familydefault}{m}{n}
\let\mathrm\mathrM % not sure why I can't declare this directly
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
a $a,\mathrm{a},\mathgt{a}$
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The behavior is common to commands defined with `\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet`. I wonder who wrote the code.

Comment: @egreg do you mean common in general (I couldn't reproduce) or common for luatex-ja in beamer fonts?

Comment: I had the same problem with `\mathcal`

Comment: Solved in luatexja 20161017.0 release